# how to show that $V( Y-X^2 )$ is irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

show that  $V( Y-X^2 )$ is irreducible.

$Y-X^2$ is an irreducible polynomial ($Y-X^2$ cann't be factored into more irreducible components). Can we conclude that $V(Y-X^2)$ is irreducible??

Comment: What is $V(Y-X^2)$?

Comment: parabola @Student

Comment: What does $V(\dots)$ stand for? What does it denote?

Comment: The *variety* of $Y - X^2$: the zeroes of the polynomial $Y - X^2$ in $k^2$, where $k$ is the field this is all being done over (irrelevant which field it is, in this case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to show that the corresponding ideal, which is $(Y - X^2)$, is prime. This in turn can be seen easiest by showing that its quotient ring $k[X,Y]/(Y-X^2)$ is an integral domain (or even by directly arguing that $Y - X^2$ is irreducible). Now, what is this quotient ring isomorphic to?

But, to actually answer your question: yes, from the fact that $Y - X^2$ is irreducible, you can conclude that $V(Y - X^2)$ is irreducible.

Comment: @Magdiradag Is it $k[X]$??

Comment: @TattwamasiAmrutam Yes, it is $k[X]$.

Comment: @magdiradag $K$ is a field and henc $k[X]$ is an integral domain.

Comment: @Magdiradag Does it imply that $I(V(Y-X^2))=(Y-X^2)$??

Comment: Yes, because $(Y - X^2)$ is prime, it is radical. But for the argument here you don't need that: because the ideal $I = (Y - X^2)$ is prime, the variety $V(I)$ is irreducible. (But, indeed, in general to show that $V(I)$ is irreducible, you only need that the radical of $I$ is prime.)

Answer (score 2):

$<y-x^2>=I(\{(t,t^2):t\in k\})$.Then since $<y-x^2>$ is an ideal of a set, hence $I(V(y-x^2))=<y-x^2>$ , therefore $I(V(y-x^2))$ is prime  (as $k[x][y]/<y-x^2>\cong k[x]$) and hence $V(y-x^2)$ is irreducible.

Comment: How do you know that $(y-x^2) = I(\{(t,t^2): t \in k\}$? The $\subset$ is obvious, but how about the $\supset$?

Comment: if $f$ has no common factors with $y-x^2$, then the set of points that are roots to them both, is finite.