# Prove that $(Y-X^2) = I\left( \{(t,t^2): t \in K\} \right)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I [commented on this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759112/how-to-show-that-v-y-x2-is-irreducible#comment7065667_2240321) 6 days ago asking why $(Y-X^2) = I\left( \{(t,t^2): t \in K\} \right)$. I can see the $\subset$, though not the $\supset$.

Let $F = Y-X^2$. We need to show that if $G(a,a^2) = 0$ for all $a \in K$, then $F$ is a factor of $G$. It makes sense intuitively, but I'm not sure how one would go about it. Any hints?

Comment: Division algorithm in $(K[X])[Y],$ maybe?  You get a remainder which is a polynomial in $p(X) \in K[X]$ such that $p(a) = 0$ for all $a \in K.$  For infinite fields (e.g. $K$ is algebraically closed) this solves it.  I don't know how to deal with finite fields with the possibility of $\deg p \geq |K|$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $h\in K[X,Y]$ one can write $h(x,y)=u(x,y)(y-x^2)+v(x)$. Then $h$
vanishes on all $(a,a^2)$ iff $v$ does, that is iff $v(a)=0$ for all $a$. As long as $K$ is an infinite field, this means that $K$ is the zero polynomial.