# $V(Y-X^2)$ is irreducible in $A^2(C)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I need to show that $V(Y-X^2)$ is irreducible. I know there was already a similiar post with answers, but I did not understand those.

[how to show that $V( Y-X^2 )$ is irreducible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759112/how-to-show-that-v-y-x2-is-irreducible)

If I knew that  $I(\{(a,a^2)\mid a \in \mathbb C \}) = (X^2-Y)$ , then $I(V(I\{(a,a^2) \mid a \in \mathbb C \}) = (X^2 - Y)$. Because $Y-X^2$ is irreducible it is prime, so $Y-X^2$ is prime. Therefore $(V(I\{(a,a^2)\mid a \in \mathbb C \})$ is an irreducible algebraic set.

Why is $I(${$(a,a^2)| a \in \mathbb C $}$)$ = $(X^2-Y)$?

Comment: You can show the ideal $(X^2-Y)$ is prime by considering the quotient ring $\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2-Y)$. Do you see why this is an integral domain?

Comment: Hint: You can either show this by brute force, or by defining a new degree function assigning $X$ the degree 1 and $Y$ the degree 2.

Comment: I showed that $Y-X^2$ is irreducible and then it follows that $Y-X^2$ is prime, so $(Y-X^2)$ is prime. I hope this is ok. I wasnt sure how to show that the kernel of the map you suggested me is $(X^2-Y)$. Anyways what I am struggling with is the equality $I(${$(a,a^2)| a \in \mathbb C $}$)$ = $(X^2-Y)$.

Comment: Have you tried showing that $\{(a,a^2)\mid a\in \mathbb{C}\}$=$V(X^2-Y)$?

Comment: Yes I already showed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $Y-X^2$ vanishes on all points of the form $(a,a^2)$, so $Y-X^2\in I$. Now we claim that $Y-X^2$ generates $I$. Choose an arbitrary polynomial $p(X,Y)$ in $I$. We apply the division algorthim and divide $p$ as a polynomial in $Y$ by $Y-X^2$: this gives us that $p(X,Y)=q(X,Y)*(Y-X^2)+r(X,Y)$. We now note that $r$ has degree zero as a polynomial in $Y$ , which means it's a polynomial in only $X$. So $r(X)$ vanishes on all points of the form $(a,a^2)$, and it must actually be the zero polynomial. This shows that $I=(Y-X^2)$, as we can write any polynomial in $I$ as a multiple of $Y-X^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why can I use the division Algorithm? Is $\mathbb (C[X])[Y]$ euclidean? Under which circumstances does the division algorithm apply?

Comment: I guess I'm cheating a little bit there, but the solution is not hard: run the division algorithm in $\Bbb C(X)[Y]$ and note that everything happens inside the subring $\Bbb C[X][Y]$. Alternatively, if $p(X,Y)=\sum a_{ij}X^iY^j$, then $p-\sum a_{ij}X^i(Y^j-X^{2j})$ is exactly $r(X,Y)$ and you can immediately see it's a polynomial in only $X$

Comment: Ah ok, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dude1662 If this answers your question, please click the green checkmark over on the left to accept the answer. If you find this answer useful, please click the up-arrow on the left.

Comment: I cannot, upvote yet because I lack the reputation. Otherwise I would.

Comment: @Dude1662 I always forget about that restriction - looks like you passed the 15 reputation threshold a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 1):

By Hilbert Nullstellensatz, $IV(Y-X^2)=rad(Y-X^2)=(Y-X^2)$, the second equality since $(Y-X^2)$ is prime.

Comment: This exercise was before Hilberts Nullstellensatz was mentioned. Is there any way of proving it without Hilberts Nullstellensatz? If it helps at all a Lemma in the chapter was that an algebraic set $V$ is irreducible iff $I(V)$ is prime.