# How to show $Z(y)$ and $Z(y^2-x)$ are irreducible algebraic sets of $\mathbb{A}_k^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I know they are irreducible, but I tried to reason it and it was harder than I thought. I tried to do this supposing they are not, so there are proper ideals of $k[x,y]$ such that
$$
\begin{array}{rclcl}
    Z(y) &=& Z(I) \cup Z(J) &=& Z(IJ); \\
    Z(y^2-x) &=& Z(K) \cup Z(L) &=& Z(LK).
\end{array}
$$

And here I get stuck. I don't know how to show that $y$ and $y^2 - x$ can't be written as a combination of products of polynomials of those ideals.

Also, I do know that $k[x,y]$ is Noetherian.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked out [other questions dealing with this same issue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759112/how-to-show-that-v-y-x2-is-irreducible)?

Comment: I haven't found any until now. Anyways, is my reasoning correct until that point?

Comment: Also, thank you for the link

Comment: Your logic isn't wrong, but it's not the most helpful either. It's better to follow the strategy in the link by showing that the ideals generated by these polynomials are prime.